# Using NSDateIntervalFormatter (or similar) to get "1 year and 2 months"

Tags: ios7, unicode, ios8, localization, nsdateformatter

Is it possible to use NSDateIntervalFormatter or similar to get a properly (and automatic) localized string like "1 year and 2 months" or "1 year, 2 months" or similar?

I guess I have to use the dateTemplate method and set up it using:
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

But reading that document, I don´t have a clear idea about how to get the words "year", "years", "month", "months"...

Basically I want to show a localized time interval using months and years in an app that is used around the world.
Any suggestion? I want to avoid having to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. For example:

```
let now = NSDate()
let past = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -100000000)

let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.Full
formatter.allowedUnits = [NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month]

let intervalString = formatter.stringFromDate(past, toDate: now)
```

For those two dates, `intervalString` is now "3 years, 2 months", and will be localized by iOS. There are other methods to get strings from (for example) a time interval instead of two date objects.

Comment: Awesome! You make my day! What are the other methods? Thanks